# Purpose and use of Wagtail/Django template tags of the form {% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}

Tags: django, wagtail

In the Wagtail docs ([Your first Wagtail site](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.11.3/getting_started/tutorial.html#extend-the-homepage-model)) we are told to create a homepage.html template as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ page.body|richtext }}
{% endblock %}
```

In the above code, what is that tag `{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}` supposed to be doing? I can't find any mention of it in the text of the tutorial.

The tutorial goes on to instruct us to create two more templates, blog_index_page and blog_page templates, both of which are to contain `{% block body_class %}` tags. Again, I can find no mention at all of those lines in the docs, let alone an explanation of how they might be used/modified.

A search for "body_class" in the docs finds only the three code blocks just mentioned, and one other mention: in the version 1.2 release notes, under 'What's new — Minor features' the notation: "Simplified `body_class` in default homepage template."

Any insight as to what I'm supposed to do with these tags? What special meaning or function, if any, does the text enclosed within the tags in those tutorial templates (for example, "template-homepage" in the code above)?

Comment: The block is defined in your `base.html` template. When you extend a template you can define custom code inside the blocks you define in your extended template. For example, if base has `{% block body_class %}` you define the same block in your extra template after extending base and you can add whatever code you want in there... This is a Django question, not specifically a Wagtail one... In your example the `body_class` code (in the tag) becomes simply `template-homepage`, when the page is rendered to the viewer that block code is replaced in what the viewer sees

Comment: @ViaTech — I have a basic understanding of how Django template tags work but I'm asking about this particular form in the Wagtail demo. "block body_class" is used in all three simple templates that a newcomer to Wagtail is supposed to build so I'm thinking it might have special significance. My thinking is, if this is just an ordinary Django tag, why do they feature it so prominently in the tutorial, but if it's a special Wagtail thing, why don't they demo it or at least tell me what it's for? (Actually since Django knowledge isn't assumed, the docs should explain it either way.)

Comment: It appears Wagtail (although I have no direct experience with it) adds base tags to the template then, there should be no special significance because it is django based, the ideas are the same. All the templating system is doing is rendering HTML to the end user based on the defined blocks you/or in this instance Wagtail declares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base.html` you have a part that looks like `<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">`. What you add into that block in your templates will be rendered into that section.

For example, lets say on your design your `<body>` contains a bottom margin, however on a particular template you don't want the margin there and create a css class `.remove-margin { margin-bottom: 0 };`

You can then add `{% block body_class %}remove-margin{% endblock %}` into your template and it will apply the class to the `<body>` tag without you having to modify the `base.html` template for that one use case.

You are also able to create your own ones. In `base.html` add a custom block such as `{% block my_custom_block %}{% endblock %}` and then in your template include some text or html inside that `my_custom_block` and it will be rendered wherever you've place that part in the base template.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the "body_class" name for this tag and the form of the tag content string are just conventions: First, the suffix "_class" indicates that the tag content should refer to a CSS class. Second, "template-homepage" string is simply a placeholder that should be replace by the actual class name. So the content of a tag name ending in "_class" should correspond to a class attribute/specifier in an HTML tag. But there's no enforcement of this convention, and if you like, you can use a "_class" tag for rendered content, or a tag with any name to refer to a CSS class. Do I have that right?

Comment: If I understood you correctly there then yes, it's just how they named it and used it for the examples but really it can be named or hold whatever, its just named there as `body_class` because it goes into the `class` attribute of the `<body>` tag. Also, if you view the source of your wagtail site you'll see it render on the web page. And while you can use it for CSS selection as is the theme of my answer, in the tutorials I think it's not just to show example of its use but mostly so you can follow along as to which template they're showing without it being explicitly mentioned each time.

Comment: I'm marking the above as the answer. Although it didn't completely address my doubt about this issue, it got me most of the way there and I now think I could write a proper answer (meaning, one that would have fully addressed my earlier confusion in one go). No time for that at the moment but will put on my to-do a clarifying edit/contribution to the Wagtail docs.

Answer (score 2):

Just to help clarify the correct answers above with a picture as I was also wondering what that block tag was doing, here is the rendered html.  As per answer above, this is standard Django.

In the base.html you have this line:

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
```

The substitution happens in the home_page.html template:

```
{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}
```

And it renders as per below screenshot:

```
 <body class="template-homepage">
```

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow could be a great way to improve the existing WagtailCMS documentation and get rewards for it. Thanks for pointing out what it does.